# Spotifty web api's giving error on ReactJS even after giving proper access tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I'm using `spotify-web-api-node` package and following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xcet6msf3eE&t) .
First I get my access token from my backend express js server then I pass it to to my reactjs application
 `spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);`

after setting the access token, I try to call the any methods that will let me use the web service helper functions it gives me the error in the screenshot.

for example : `spotifyApi.searchTracks(search).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err));`

but if I try to access this method using postman or from the express Js server using the same token it gives me no error and gives a correct response.

I was following the clone spotify tutorial from youtube and they do it from their reactJs application and it seems to work fine for them, for me however I get the error on my react application.

[image: Error in browser console]